# Why is it possible to call a function inside a class definition without creating it's object in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop

For example:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var currDir = fs.readdirSync('./lib');
console.log(currDir);
```

This code works correctly as expected. But I can't understand that how could the function fs.readdirSync() be called when the object of class fs has not been created.

```
var fsClass = require('fs');
var fs = new fsClass();
var currDir = fs.readdirSync('./lib');
console.log(currDir);
```

However, when I try to create a object and call the function on that instance, the code does not work.  Error message:

```
TypeError: fsClass is not a constructor
    at Object.<anonymous>
```

Thank You!

Comment: `fs` is not a class, just an object

Comment: @SebastianSpeitel  l so that means that when I require a core module, it comes as an object. But then how would I extract it's class?

Comment: @fliptrail why do you assume it has one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fs` is not a class but an Object. 
This object was exported so when you `require` it all of the defined functions are available.

Take a look at the code: 
https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/1375af204a30d1885b9e8bf79725cbd223707439/lib/fs.js#L1796

They export an object with functions inside of it.

Now let's say you create a class and not just a regular object (i.e `{}`), you can export it as a class or an Object

```
module.exports = SomeClass
```

or

```
modules.exports = new SomeClass();
```

Answer (score 1):

The `fs` object is already created with:

```
var fs = require('fs');
```

The `fs` module exports an object that is already created.  `fs` is not a constructor or a class.  It's an already created object that you can directly call its methods on.

A module can export any number of things.  It can export an object that is already created and already has methods on it.  It can export a constructor function that one would call to create an object.  It can export just a value.   In this particular case, the `fs` module exports an already created module that you can just call the methods on directly.  No need to execute a separate constructor to create another object.

Answer (score -1):

You need to stop thinking in the classical inheritance model that comes with Java, C# and related languages. **There are no "classes" like this languages in JavaScript**; instead, it uses a [mechanism based on prototypes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming). Even when ES2015 brings the concept of "class" to JavaScript, it is just syntax sugar for constructor functions.

So, respect to your question:

> Not everything is necessarily composed of classes in JavaScript

There are other structures and types like [`object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Basics) that is precisely the type of the `fs` module. They are just key/value structures to store data.

Comment: JavaScript has had classes for years.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

Comment: @MattMorgan There is no concept of "class" in JavaScript. The `class` keyword is just syntax sugar. Internally, classes are treated as constructor functions with prototypes.

Comment: For more information, [read this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming).

Comment: then it would be more accurate to say: "JavaScript does use classical inheritance in the same way as a language like Java or C++.  It _does_ have classes, but they use a prototypal inheritance model."  'class' means something in JavaScript, but not the same thing you would mean in Java etc.  I think that without that bit of context your answer could be very confusing.

Comment: Also, JavaScript supports both functional and object-oriented programming paradigms, so it is further misleading to suggest that it does not.